# top command not working

Tags: top

I am facing a weird error when I attempt to invoke "top"

> myhost:~> top
>
> top: unknown option '1'
>
> Usage:
>     top -hv | -bcHiOSs -d secs -n max -u|U user -p pid(s) -o field -w [cols]
>
> myhost:~>

I am connected to the server "myhost" via SSH.
I looked it up online and found no help...

EDIT: As far as I remember, I have not manipulated this command in any way. The command `\top` works.

Comment: If this is on Linux, then see if you have a `.toprc` file in your home directory, and remove or temporarily rename it. Then try again.

Comment: To ignore aliases, try `"top"` or `\top`. Also explain what did you do before you broke it. Out of the box, `top` works fine.

Comment: I do not have a `.toprc` file. Also, `\top` works.

Comment: Chances are that your machine has been compromised! and top has been replaced with a custom `top` command which is probably hiding `trojans, viruses` and whatnot!

Comment: No it is ok. This is a university-managed server. The IT people do things all the time. Thanks for the heads up, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have the top replaced with alias of the same name. Check your aliases:

```
[kucera@node ~]$ alias
...
alias top='top 1'
...
```

If you see something like in the example above, you have the problem identified. Then you have to modify your profile settings (if it wasn't just temporary alias).

Comment: I have the alias: `top top -s 1`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove the 1 so you have just 'top -s' in your alias.

Comment: I do realize that. The question is how do I do that? I have no `.bashrc` file in my home directory.

Comment: Then it's possibly system wide. Grep content of /etc/profile.d, /etc/profile, /etc/bashrc

Comment: Thank you. I will bypass it for now by using `\top` as the user val0x00ff suggested.

Comment: If you don't have access there, you can fix it with 'unalias top' in your ~/.bashrc

Comment: `unalias top` worked like a charm. Thank you! Please add this to your answer.